# My python character only moves 1 pixel at a time

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics, pixel

I am making a small little Parkour Minigame where the character jumps from platform to platform, but I can't seem to get the character to move properly.  I made another game and it worked correctly, but this one doesn't.  When I hold down the left/right arrow key it only moves 1 pixel at a time.  Here are the V

```
    Parkour_MoveLeft=Parkour_MoveRight=Parkour_Jump='no'
    Parkour_Speed=1
    Parkour_X=0
    Parkour_Y=0
    Parkour_Rows=0
    Parkour_Col=0
```

Now here is my code for the part of the game I am having trouble with :

```
    if location=='Parkour':
    Window.fill(Black)
    WindowW = 700
    WindowH = 700
    Window=pygame.display.set_mode((WindowW, WindowH),0, 32)
    pygame.draw.rect(Window, Blue, Parkour_Character)
    num=0
    for point in Parkour_Grids:
        mat=Parkour_Lvl_1[num]
        num+=1
        if mat=='a':
            point['collide']='no'
        if mat=='p':
            pygame.draw.rect(Window, Green, point['rect'])
            point['collide']='yes'

    for point in Parkour_Grids:
        if point['collide']=='yes':
            if Parkour_Character.colliderect(point['left']):
                Parkour_MoveRight='no'
            if Parkour_Character.colliderect(point['right']):
                Parkour_MoveLeft='no'
            if Parkour_Character.colliderect(point['bottom']):
                Parkour_MoveUp='no'
            if Parkour_Character.colliderect(point['top']):
                Parkour_MoveDown='no'
```

## Parkour Movement

```
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                Parkour_MoveRight='yes'
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                Parkour_MoveLeft='yes'
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                Parkour_MoveRight='no'
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                Parkour_MoveLeft='no'
    if Parkour_MoveLeft=='yes':
        Parkour_Character.right-=Parkour_Speed
    if Parkour_MoveRight=='yes':
        Parkour_Character.right+=Parkour_Speed
```

## Level Map

```
    Parkour_Lvl_1=['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'a','p','p','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'a','a','a','a','a','p','p','p','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',
           'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a']

    while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
Parkour_Grids.append({'rect':pygame.Rect(Parkour_X, Parkour_Y, 80, 30),'right':1,'left':1,'top':1,'bottom':1,'type':'air','collide':'yes'})
Parkour_X+=80
Parkour_Col+=1
if Parkour_Col==40:
    Parkour_Col=0
    Parkour_X=0
    Parkour_Y+=70
    Parkour_Rows+=1
    if Parkour_Rows==10:
        break
    for point in Parkour_Grids:
        point['right']=pygame.Rect(point['rect'].left+70,point['rect'].top , 6, 70)
        point['left']=pygame.Rect(point['rect'].right-76,point['rect'].top , 6, 70)
        point['top']=pygame.Rect(point['rect'].left+6,point['rect'].top-15 , 58, 6)
        point['bottom']=pygame.Rect(point['rect'].left+6,point['rect'].bottom+6 , 58,6)
```

Anyone have any help on what I can do?  It's the exact same code at another game I made (with different variables), but this one doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you want to move left, are you supposed to subtract `right` and `left` by the same amount?

Comment: I wasn't sure, but I had tried both ways and neither worked.

Comment: looks fine by me. Are you sure that parkour_speed is not 1?

Comment: Parkour_Speed is set to 1, but I don't think that is the problem.  For I have another program which uses the same coding as this one and the speed is set to one and it still works.

Comment: What happens if you increase the speed..?

Comment: @Gaspump1112 that is exactly the problem, you are moving 2 pixels each frame, once when you adjust right, and once when you adjust left

Comment: besides that, why even 2 coordinates? its a single one for one direction o.O

Comment: Adrian, If I increase the speed, the character moves more pixels at a time, but the problem stays the same sadly.  And it's not that I want it to move 1 pixel at a time, I want it to continually move in a direction when I hold down a button.

Comment: Okay, I changed it a little bit but the error still occurs.

Comment: are you resetting your `Parkour_MoveRight` and `Parkour_MoveLeft` variable inside your main loop?

Comment: No, should I be doing that?

Comment: nope, but the problem seems to be outside of what you are showing us

Comment: Okay, should I post the whole code then?

Comment: Okay, I added more to the code, does any of that help?

Comment: do you collide every time?

Comment: No . . . I guess I should put in the level map.

Comment: Okay, do you see anything that could be causing this error?

Comment: nope, what I would do is put in some print or log statements to find out where things are not what you expect them to be.  For instance anyplace you change your move flags.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I now see what is wrong.  Whenever I press a key down, it immediately goes up . . . I just need to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: even if you keep the key pressed?

Comment: yeah, and I don't know whats wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

You need to raise Parkour_Speed. It is set to one, and because it does not look like you have ever multiplied it or implemented a movement twice, that is exactly how many pixels it will move. Upping this number will make it move more pixels at one time. However, while it isn't explicitly clear if this is your issue, it is also possible that it is not moving continuously when you press the button. If the event finder is not being run constantly, this will definitely happen, however because checking events is implemented at the same time, this is probably not the case (with more code it would be easier to know). Another thing that you must repeatedly implement to continuously move your sprite across the screen is where you sync Parkour_X and Y with the screen. I do not see where you do this in the code, but I think it should be easiest to use the move_ip function to solve your problems. Provided that the screen is being updated, this modification to your code should solve your issues:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                Parkour_MoveRight='yes'
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                Parkour_MoveLeft='yes'
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                Parkour_MoveRight='no'
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                Parkour_MoveLeft='no'
if Parkour_MoveLeft=='yes':
    Parkour_Character.move_ip(-Parkour_Speed,0)
if Parkour_MoveRight=='yes':
    Parkour_Character.move_ip(Parkour_Speed,0)
```

If this also does not solve your problem, everything else seems fine, so it may be useful to include even more code. I know you have a lot of code up already, but simple features in graphical programs such as this one tend to be very interconnected.